# Declaring extern NSString causes  linker error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, boolean

This is ridiculous, im trying to create a sound bool to turn of in app sounds. I  keep getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_kPlaySoundPrefsKey", referenced from:
  -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have checked that all my files are linked in build phases, I have deleted the appdelegate .m where im getting the error before I even get to call the bool in any of my view controllers,  and re imported it in build phases. Checked I have relevant framweworks in place.  I have even checked a previous app I made with same code and the code it appears to be exactly the same with no error (built with previous version of xcode).  Taking it right back to basics I get the error as soon as I add the following code to my App Delegate,

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
extern NSString *kPlaySoundPrefsKey;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> 

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

NSDictionary *defaultDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
 forKey:kPlaySoundPrefsKey];

return YES;
}
```

If I change `extern NSString *kPlaySoundPrefsKey;` to  `NSString *kPlaySoundPrefsKey;` it builds then crashes...Im out of ideas now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys

I added

`NSString *kPlaySoundPrefsKey = @"playSoundKey";`

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultDict];`

to app delegate.  That fixed it

Answer (score 18):

When you declaring something as `extern` you are telling the compiler the type AND that you will define it somewhere else. In your case you never define your variable.

So in your .h you would have:

```
extern NSString* kPlaySoundPrefsKey;
```

But in some .m you must also have

```
NSString* kPlaySoundPrefsKey = @"play_sounds"; // or some value
```

Since in your case these are constants you can also specify:

```
extern NSString* const kPlaySoundPrefsKey;
```

and

```
NSString* const kPlaySoundPrefsKey = @"play_sounds";
```

The addition of the const qualifier will cause a compiler error if someone ever writes something like

```
kPlaySoundPrefsKey = @"some_other_value";
```

Answer (score 7):

I am also got the same error even if I am  properly declared and define the extern const string , 
The problem is, my constant file not in the compile source list .

**Make sure that your .m file  appears in the "Compile Sources" Build Phase for your build target. Sometimes, adding files to a project in Xcode doesn't add all implementation files to the appropriate targets.**

Hope this will helpful for some people.
Refe: [linker-error-undefined-symbols-symbols-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357311/linker-error-undefined-symbols-symbols-not-found)

Answer (score 4):

First, ensure it is defined:

```
// AppDelegate.h
extern NSString* const kPlaySoundPrefsKey; // << declaration

// AppDelegate.m
NSString * const kPlaySoundPrefsKey = @"kPlaySoundPrefsKey";  // << definition
```

see also:

["extern const" vs "extern" only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296197/extern-const-vs-extern-only/7296223#7296223)

[3 questions about extern used in an Objective-C project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330048/3-questions-about-extern-used-in-a-objective-c-project/7330190#7330190)

[Linker error using extern "C" in Objective-C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376003/linker-error-using-extern-c-in-objective-c-code/7376015#7376015)

Comment: I down voted the original answer because it did not address the root cause of the OP's problem; he was never defining the variable. Once you edited it to address this I removed it.

Comment: @idz alright. i received two separate anon downvotes (which have both been undone now), one of which came *after* the update which mentioned the absence definition. so, i found it a bit unusual. thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Does C++ name mangle variables?  I thought it only did that with functions.

Comment: @JeremyP in this case (toolchain+abi+etc.), the exported name is the same. will remove that part. cheers.

Comment: Could you explain about the usage of `extern` here, it doesn't seem constant in the Apple header files to have this. Sometimes there is only `NSString *const`, other times `extern NSString *const`, and sometimes `extern NSString *`

Comment: @Daniel a) could you provide an example header b+c) the only difference is that c may be assigned another string -- the string it 'points to' may be set during execution. for a pref key or notification name, it should be `const`

Comment: ninja downvoters? lol! long time @justin it's good to see your answers again :)