# extern causing Linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, extern

Seems to be almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186631/declaring-extern-nsstring-causes-linker-error), but the answer there hasn't addressed the problem.

first.h

```
extern PlanningDocumentService *folderService;
```

first.m

```
#import first.h

- (void)serviceDefinition
 {    
    PlanningDocumentService *folderService = [_myDocumentViews objectAtIndex:[_gridView indexOfSelectedItem]];   
    detail.service = folderService;
 }
```

second.h

```
#import first.h
```

second.m

```
#import second.h

+(NSArray*)getDocumentData
{
     NSString *passedCaption =  folderService.caption;
}
```

Gives the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_folderService", referenced from:
      +[GenericService getDocumentData] in GenericService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I haven't declared or defined `folderService` anywhere other than the files above.
Any ideas welcomed.

Comment: where is folderService created? you just put the extern but you actually have to create the var

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `folderService` to have global scope:

first.m:

```
#import "first.h"

PlanningDocumentService *folderService = nil;

- (void)serviceDefinition
{    
    folderService = [_myDocumentViews objectAtIndex:[_gridView indexOfSelectedItem]];   
    detail.service = folderService;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`PlanningDocumentService *folderService` within `- (void)serviceDefinition` makes the variable local to the function, but not global. But `extern PlanningDocumentService *folderService` declares the existence of a global variable, that is never defined.

Comment: Also bang on. Would've accepted both answers if it were allowed. =)
Thanks.